# Регулярное выражение на проверку логина

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Помогите составить регулярное выражение для проверки логина. Логин может состоять из латинских букв и цифр и двух символов "_" и "-", причем начинаться может только с латинских букв! Я сделал так:

```
pattern = /^[\D](.*)[\w]/;
```

Но тогда, если вводишь nick##, то return pattern.test(text) возвратит true...

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем сам сделал и проверил, пока что вполне устраивает меня. Приведу код функции:

```
function checkLogin(loginString){
    pattern = /^[a-zA-Z](.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$/;
    return pattern.test(loginString);
}
```

Comment: Хм, а разве точка в регулярных выражениях не означает любой символ?
И зачем ещё скобки?

Comment: Если так: 
^[a-zA-Z](.*)$

то, например, login@12412 пройдет

Comment: Нет ну так вы разрешаете логины где после латинской буквы идут любые символы.
И скобки непонятно зачем, если только вы их не используете чтобы потом обратиться к этой части распознанной строки

Comment: Замечания по регекспу.  
1. Скобки не нужны  
2. Точка не нужна  
3. Тире в символьных классах надо ставить в начале, чтобы не допустить неоднозначности и тире не стало метасимволом  
4. Упростить выражение очень легко флагом игнора регистра  
В итоге получаем:  

    /^[a-z][-a-z_]*$/i

Answer (score 3):

Рискну предположить:

```
/^[a-z]+([-_]?[a-z0-9]+){0,2}$/i
```

Начинается и кончается на `букву/цифру` и содержит не более двух `"_"/"-"` и не подряд. Т.е. пропустит "`admin_0-15`", "`user`", "`user-lol`" и не пропустит "`admin--12`", "`user_lol-`", "`lamer--`", "`-a-`"

Comment: Без знака вопроса оно понятнее, потому что, если у `[-_]` будет ноль вхождений, то движок регексов просто посчитает, что проверяемый текст полностью соответствует `[a-z]+` и ноль вхождений второй части регэкспа.  

    [-_][a-z0-9]+

Comment: @Sh4dow ваше выражение не примет логин a6-b-b

Comment: `/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*?([-_][a-z0-9]+){0,2}$/i`

Comment: @ReinRaus вот последнее - да, точно, даже исправлять не буду)

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет такого выражения ? Как по мне самый простой вариант и вроде как работает ) Хотя я могу ошибаться )

```
var m = login.match(/^(\w+){3,32}$/)
```

Answer (score -3):

Смело заявляю, что это лучшая функция на проверку валидности логина, и не надо придумывать ничего нового.

```
function isValidLogin(str){
   return /^[\w]{6,}$/i.test(str);
}
```

Comment: данное выражение не соответствует требованиям указанным в вопросе.